# ISL28022 Maximum Ratings - Differential Voltage

Tags: current, monitor

I would like to use the Renesas ISL28022 Precision Digital Power Monitor to measure the current through a shunt resistor and I'm not sure I fully understand the [datasheet](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/698/REN_isl28022_DST_20160128-1998382.pdf).

So the way I intend to use it, right after the shunt there is a a switch (shunt and switch is an encapsulated component), and therefore one leg of the ISL28022 input will be connected to high-voltage (58V) and the other leg will be floating when the switch is disconnected.
Will this be a problem for the ISL28022 considering the maximum Differential Input Voltage (VINP, VINM) is ±63V?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUAZci.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Additionally, the voltage across the shunt might be larger than 1V. I do not care if the measurement is not correct at that point as I can ignore it, but I want to be sure that the device (current monitor) will still function properly after returning to normal values (up to 320mV). I am unsure what the datasheet means by the "diodes" in this paragraph from the datasheet:

"Over-Ranging It is not recommended to operate the ISL28022 outside the set voltage range. In the event of measuring a shunt voltage beyond the maximum set range (320mV) and lower than the clamp voltage of the protection diode (1V), the measured output reading may be within the accepted range but will be incorrect."

Does this mean that any drop-out larger than 1V on the shunt will go through clamping diodes and to VCC? So if VINP is connected to 58V and VINN in connected to ground (through load while SW1 is OFF), then all of VS (58V) will go through clamping diodes to ISL28022's VCC? If so, then I don't understand how they say that the maximum differential voltage is +-63V. But maybe the clamping diodes don't work how I think they do, or maybe they clamp to VBUS?

Comment: Yes, the Over-Ranging section does not contain a good explanation. To me it is not obvious, where these 1 V protection diodes are located. I assume, there are series resistors inside, that meet at a clamping diode pair in front of the amplifier.